# nested serialize Django object

Tags: django, django-models, django-serializer

hi guys i want to serialize my model's object. and my model like this :

```
class User (models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   family_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

and i have another model like this:

```
class Child (models.Model):
   little_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   user = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
```

i want to serialize one of my child object with all fields in user field for example like this:

```
{"id": 1 ,
 "little_name": "Sam",
 "user": {"id": 1,
          "name": "Karim",
          "family_name":"Kari"
         }
}
```

i use model_to_dict() and **dict**() and serializer of django but i can't get user field compeletly and they return it like this :

```
{"id": 1 ,
 "little_name": "Sam",
 "user": "id": 1,
}
```

and **i don't want to use django rest serializer**
what can i do ?!?

Comment: write your own function is the best thing I can think of since you don't want to use the DRF's serializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use model_to_dict twice:

```py
child_dict = model_to_dict(child)
child_dict['user'] = model_to_dict(child.user)
```